# twisted pair vs single ended usb

Tags: ethernet, cable, layer1

I would like to understand what is the difference between twisted pair and single ended USB with the other hand having an ethernet port.

My colleague mentioned that both ends have to be ethernet for the cable to be a twisted pair. Is this true?

Pardon my question as i am very new to such networking stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unshielded twisted pair (UTP) cabling is the most common type of cabling.  It is used for everything from standard phone lines to ethernet cabling.  UTP is graded by category.  The twisted pairs reduce problems from external noise and crosstalk.

USB cables may or may not have twisted pairs, depending on the manufacturer and quality of the cabling.  There is an adapter in the USB cable/connector to allow ethernet to connect via USB.  The ethernet side will need UTP.

The cable from the ethernet port on your adapter will need to be UTP to the next ethernet device.  Ethernet, at modern network speeds, is quite sensitive to how far the pairs can be untwisted at the ends of the cable, so there will be almost no untwisting beyond the tiny bit needed to fit the individual wires into the connector.